# new Sokcet(ip,port) works in a java project, but fail when in android

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity

I'm developing an android app using socket. But `Socket soc=new Socket(ip,port)` always give me a `SocketTimeoutException`. I use socket in a java project, it's Ok. But not in an android project.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Socket soc=new Socket("192.168.177.103",8888);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is all right, but not in an android project. Why?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mmmm);

    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                Socket soc=new Socket("192.168.177.103",8888);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_mmmm, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Could someone tell me why? Thank you very much.
The Exception details when use socket in android:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:361)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:732)
at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:152)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
at com.example.mmmmm.MMMMActivity$1.run(MMMMActivity.java:26)
```

Comment: `192.168.177.103` is a LAN IP - is your android device connected to the LAN (via VPN or Wifi for example)?

Comment: Check if you have granted Internet permission for your application. Also, @assylias may be right.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure the device is connected. And I also use the same ip in a java project, and the server can successfully get this client socket. I'm confused why it doesn't work in android project.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas Thank you, but also no problem with the internet permission. (Platform 4.2, API levl 17). I'm so confused.

Comment: Need the stack trace for more.

Comment: Audrius does not mean the API level.  Have you added the requested permission to the manifest?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas The exception details is given, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have added the permission to the manifest.xml. And with the information of my application, you can have a test to see if your platform have the same problem. Thank you, @Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Your server 192.168.177.103 is not responding in timely manner, or at all. It may also be that the port 8888 is closed by its firewall. So this is actually not the Android device problem.

If the returned content is HTTP based, use some desktop PC connected to the same LAN to check if the server responds to the ordinary browser request. Also, try

```
 adb shell ping 192.168.177.103
```

This would allow to verify if the server is accessible. However ping may be disabled on your server, especially if it is a Windows machine.

If the server is accessible from desktop connected through the wired network and is still not accessible from Android, it may also be great to check how the firewall of your wireless router is configured.